# Connection string for Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to connect to the access 2010 database from excel.I am using VBA.I wrote the connection string as

```
Public objCon As New ADODB.Connection

objCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
            "\asset_database.accdb;ACE OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
```

But it is giving the error "could not find installable ISAM".What is this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oddly enough, it is Jet OLEDB Password, not ACE:

```
objCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path _
   & "\asset_database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
```

See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Answer (score 2):

Try "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\asset_database.accdb;JET OLEDB:Database Password=password;"

Answer (score -1):

If you have Access installed, or you install the Access Database Engine on the workstation that has the Excel spreadsheet open, then you don't need to create an OLEDB connection; you can just open a database object as follows:

```
dim db as database

set db=opendatabase("c:\db path\my db.accdb")
```